# Vlookup not registering range changes in calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Typing the first vlookup yields the correct result. When I pull down the cell reference to use the same vlookup on other cells, the vlookup recognizes that the formula has changed, but still delivers the result in the first cell.

Example

LookupValue     Formula                                     Result

A4A             VLOOKUP(E5,Sheet1!$A$5:$N$224,6,FALSE)     .0716243
AAAE            VLOOKUP(E6,Sheet1!$A$5:$N$224,6,FALSE)     .0716243

When I manually re-enter 'E6,' in the second row, the result value changes, but the same thing occurs when I pull that cell reference down (to copy).

I have all ways I know to convert the lookup values to numbers, but when I check them with =isnumber(), I am still receiving 'FALSE'. Is this the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not a problem if E5/E6 etc. are text values as long as the values you are matching with, i.e. Sheet1 A5:A224 are also text values - looks like they are, otherwise you would get #N/A

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your calculation is set to Manual. Either set your calculations to Automatic or press <kbd>F9</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) after you have dragged / copied your calculations to fill the range.